# How to refer to several titled individuals, "Mr x,y,z PhD"?

Tags: abbreviations, salutations

How does one abbreviate "Mr Adams PhD, Mr Benson PhD, Mr Charles PhD" to use just one salutation and one title.

Comment: Do note that with a PhD each, these are "Doctors Adams, Benson and Charles" which solves both problems easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are seeking "Messrs." which is an abbreviation of the French ['Messieurs'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Messrs.) and is commonly used in English as a plural for "Mr."

Example usage:

> Dear Messrs. Jones, Adams and Jefferson,

See [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/messrs.) and [Cambridge Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/messrs) for further details.

Comment: Oddly, the female equivalent, *Mesdames*, is not abbreviated.

Comment: @TimLymington - I believe you would be looking for Mmes. or Mses. depending on your location and intended recipient.  See: https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/orthographe-spelling/mme-mrs-eng.html

Comment: @MrWonderful You could mention that *Messrs* is short for the French *Messieurs*. Interestingly I have never seen *Mesdames* shortened to *Mmes* in English, though it is routinely so shortened in French. Americans, in my experience rarely use *Messrs*. They will often begin a formal business letter *Gentlemen*. I'm not sure how they would write Mr Jones, Mr Smith and Mr Bullfinch.

Comment: @WS2 -Oddly, it took me 7 links down Google's results before I found a source to show that.  I've updated the answer accordingly.  Thanks!  Oh, and my Mom has used Messrs. in business correspondence ever since the '60s.